# make asymmetric pairwise comparisons in a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix with pairwise values but no symmetric, I mean, AxB is not the same as BxA. Here is a dummy example:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
A    1  0.7  0.8  0.8  0.9
B  0.2    1  0.2  0.8  0.3
C  0.3  0.4    1  0.5  0.6
D  0.4  0.9  0.8    1  0.4
E  0.8  0.2  0.8  0.8    1
```

I need to know how many `[i,j]` comparisons are higher or equal than 0.7 and how many comparisons `[j,i]` are also higher than `0.7` in order to remove high redundant elements. In the example, element `A` has a higher number of elements with `B, C, D, and E` and it should be removed in further analysis. I've thought in using `table` command for this

```
table1 <- apply(M, 1, table)
table2 <- apply(M, 2, table)
```

And then compare table1 with table2 for removing the redundant elements, does it would be a good approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do with the entries > 0.7? Set them to NA? Remove them? Regardless, this should get you going in the right direction:

```
#Assumes your data is named x
> which(x > 0.7, arr.ind = TRUE)
#----
  row col
A   1   1
E   5   1
B   2   2
D   4   2
...

#Set values = NA
x[which(x>0.7, arr.ind = TRUE)] <- NA
#---
    A   B   C   D   E
A  NA 0.7  NA  NA  NA
B 0.2  NA 0.2  NA 0.3
C 0.3 0.4  NA 0.5 0.6
D 0.4  NA  NA  NA 0.4
E  NA 0.2  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase, I like your second approach. Actually, these pairwise values are number of shared elements between AxB, BxA, etc., being A a list of 4 elements and B a list of 7 elements. Thus, I would like to remove those items that are shared in a high percentage among A, B, C, ... Following your approach I could count the number of NAs in rows and columns and then remove those with a value above a threshold that I choose, in this dummy example would be a shared index above 0.7 in 4/5 elements, and, thus I should remove A from my matrix.

Comment: shorter version: `x[x>0.7] <- NA`